# sql server: stored procedure into temporary table WITH variables values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a temporary table

```
@MyTmpTable(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

and my stored procedure `SP1` returns 3 columns values

I can use:

```
insert into @MyTmpTable (col2, col3, col4) exec SP1
```

to fill `@MyTmpTable` but `col1` value will always be `null`, is there any way I can do something like this?

```
declare @var1 varchar(10) = 'myvalue';
insert into @MyTable(col2, col3, col4) @var1, exec SP1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not a temporary table. It's a table variable. There are differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just update col1 after the insert:

```
update @MyTmpTable set col1 = 'myvalue' where col1 is null;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, thanks! I am not familiar with TSQL, I used PSQL, at this point, I think PSQL is more efficient, I can use SP just like another table, even with joins

Answer (score 1):

if your col1 is always null,you can create it with  default value for your requirement to work .see below for demo

```
create table #test
(
id int default null,
id1 int,
id2 int
)


create proc usp_test
as
begin
select rand()*10,rand()*20
end

insert into #test
(id1,id2)
exec usp_test
```

Comment: actually, `default null` is quite meaningless, I would go with an actual value...